# Why wont this onclick event run my iframe function?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Why doesn't this iframe work? I can't figure it out. It runs just fine without being called from the onClick.

```js
function paymentMethods() {
  var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  x.setAttribute("id", "paymentIframe");
  // DELETE
  var y = ("tml_text.asp");
  //Change link to payments link and change y to accountID
  var z = ("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/h" + y );
  x.setAttribute("src", z);
  x.height = "700";
  x.width = "500";
  $("#iframeDiv1").append(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iframeDiv1"></div>
<div id="iframeDiv2"></div>
<button id="paymentMethodsBtn" onClick="paymentMethods()">Payment Methods</button>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". After adding jQuery to the snippet, it looks like the code is "working"?

Comment: Console log will probably show you that paymentMethods isn't defined, right? https://jsfiddle.net/0qd6dpq4/1/ - do it like this...

Comment: @Gunvalk I tried you code on jsbin, the frame doesn't show up because: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsbin.com/qukevariha/edit?html,js,output' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Did you get the similar error?